# robocopy minage maxage not working

Tags: cmd, robocopy

Trying to use robocopy to move cctv recordings into folders by year. Then possibly by month. There are 392,131 files. I understand the robocopy date it formatted `yyyymmdd`.

```
robocopy d:\ipcam\ d:\ipcam2014 /MOV /minage:20140101 /maxage:20141231
```

I was not sure the values were being treated as a date. I tested entering an incorrect date and i throws an error.

The system is an *Windows XP SP3* also tried over the network from *Windows 7* but same result - **all files skipped.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> /MAXAGE:n :: MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
>   /MINAGE:n :: MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.

So MINAGE will exclude files newer than 20140101
And MAXAGE will exclude files older than 20141231

So none would be selected.

If you want 20140101-20141231, try swapping the values between MINAGE and MAXAGE

So MINAGE will exclude files newer than 20141231
And MAXAGE will exclude files older than 20140101

Comment: Thanks. It's running now. I think the move is implemented within robocopy as a copy then a delete so its using loads of disk resources. I think i will need another solution maybe vbscipt?